# Question about backshifting in reported speech

Tags: backshifting

What option is right?

1. He said he had been there when I was there.
2. He said he had been there when I had been there.

Should the when-clause be in the past perfect if the main one is in the past perfect to emphasize simultaneity? What rule can explain that?

Comment: I'd parse 1) as *him saying* and *you being there* being simultaneous, and *him being/having been there* being the only thing reported - if everything after *said* is meant to be reported, it should align in tense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic rules for backshifting say how each verb should be backshifted. There's no exception in the rules for "when"-clauses.

Your sentence 2 follows those rules correctly, it has the meaning you intend, and it's 100% natural.

That said, there are times when we don't have to exactly follow those rules because the meaning stays the same and it still sounds natural. That might be what you're asking about here, about sentence 1, and the answer is no, in this case, sentence 1 would probably be understood correctly, but is grammatically incorrect.

I'm going to change your first sentence a bit to make it easier to follow the meaning of "there":

> 1. He said he had been *in traffic* when I was *in traffic*.

This sentence means, "When I was in traffic, he said that he (too) had been in traffic (earlier)," which means he said that after he was out of the traffic, but while I was still in it.

Comment: Thank for your answer, mister!